# SQL set allowed values for a column

Tags: oracle, constraint, alter-table, default-value

I want to make an `ALTER TABLE` expression which adds a new column and sets a default value and additionaly defines the allowed values for that column. It's a text column, and allowed should be only 'value1', 'value2' and 'value3'. Default should be 'value1'

According to following syntax diagrams:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm getting to this point

```
ALTER TABLE exampleTable ADD COLUMN new_column VarChar(20) DEFAULT 'value1'
```

but I'm absolutely not sure how to set the allowed values.

Is it possible to make somethin like

CONSTRAINT CHECK new_column IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3)

? I must admit the `search condition` diagram is quite confusing me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
alter table ExampleTable
    add (new_column varchar(20) default 'value1',
         constraint ckExampleTable check (new_column in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')));
```

Comment: @Phil - Apart from the `go` looks valid per my reading of the diagram and works fine in Oracle [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1dd93/1)

Answer (score 8):

You should actually do this as two different statements:

```
ALTER TABLE test
    ADD new_column VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'value1'

ALTER TABLE test
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_exampleTable_newColumn CHECK (new_column IN ('value1','value2','value3'))
```

Comment: As a note, this is SQL Server syntax since I answered the question prior to when it had the Oracle tag and appeared to be SQL Server to me.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (column_name IN ('aaa', 'bbb', ...))
```